# Gradle Multi Project build with multiple code repositories

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to find a solution to a multi-project gradle build with projects residing in different code repositories:

For demonstration purposes let's call the projects: core, lib1, lib2 and lib3. All these projects historically exist in different code repositories. It would obviously be possible to merge the lib* projects into the main code repository and set up a multi-project build. `core`, `lib1` and `lib2` are public code repositories, `lib3` however is an unpublished repository/library that I want to keep private for the time being.

The question boils down to:
- Can I get a multi project build without merging the repositories?
- Can I have `lib3` have a compile dependency to `core`?

Comment: historically, how did the compile dependency exist?

Comment: It didn't really. `core` was built locally, the jar copied over to a `libs/` directory in the sub projects.

Comment: You can add any arbitrary project or jar from the file system as a dependency `compile files('path/to/a.jar', 'path/to/b.jar')`

Comment: How about using git submodules? Are those git repose?

Comment: @Opal Thought about using submodules too, but they're tricky to handle and always require a manual update. This would also mean having a private submodule that people without access can't check out.

Comment: @RaGe Does that work without having built jars? `lib3` is still in development and might require changes to `core` so it would be preferable to depend on the latest source instead of a build artifact.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to depend directly on source from a different project. It is however possible to: *include source from the other project as a sourceset, or likely cleaner: *trigger a build in the other project and then depend on the generated artifact.